# How to solve java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while doing react native project

Tags: react-native, android-studio, unsatisfiedlinkerror

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by "/data/app/~~7G6bfzz_ymffNERRYfMwmQ==/com.examp-A5s_wYrpMFdGAfa3G9Phhw==/lib/arm64/libfolly_runtime.so"

getting this error while opening the application on device

tried ndk parameter , but did'nt solved this issue
ndk {
abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.